# categories from csv column values

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, tree

I have a CSV file of items with columns like `item_id | item_name | item_cat1 | item_cat2 | item_cat3`. I'm parsing this file into one large array containing arrays of each item's info:

```
$items = Array(
  1 => Array(
    item_id => item1,
    item_name => item1,
    item_cat1 => cat1,
    item_cat2 => cat2,
    item_cat3 => cat3
  ),
  2 => Array(
    item_id => item2,
    item_name => item2,
    item_cat1 => cat4,
    item_cat2 => cat5,
    item_cat3 => cat6
  ),
  3 => Array(
    item_id => item3,
    item_name => item3,
    item_cat1 => cat1,
    item_cat2 => cat7,
    item_cat3 => ''
  )
)
```

What I would like to do is create a new array with the categories nested within:

```
$cats = Array(
  1 => Array(
    'cat_name' => cat1,
    'subs' => Array(
      1 => cat2,
      2 => cat7
    )
  )
)
```

But somehow it needs to be recursive, getting an array of the third level as well, if the third level contains an entry.

How can this be achieved?

EDIT-
Here's what I have so far, and kind of a short code of what I want to accomplish:

```
$mainCats = array();

foreach($items as $item){
    if(!in_array($item[10], $mainCats)){
        $mainCats[] = array(
            'cat_name' = > $item[10],
            'cat_subs' => array()
    }
    // if $item[11] does not exist in cat_subs where $mainCats['cat_name'] == $item[10], add it.
    // else check if $item[12] exists in cat_subs where $mainCats['cat_subs']['cat_name'] == $item[11]
}
```

The problem with the existing code is that since `$item[10]` is in an array within the `$mainCats` array, it adds every occurance, instead of only one.

Comment: means you want to create an array with distinct value of `item_cat1`

Comment: You mean something like this, but in PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661877/generate-tree-structure-from-csv

Comment: @Kamil something to that effect, yes

Comment: So this is called tree structure. Google it, there are a lot of examples in many languages, including PHP. I cant help, my PHP is too bad to teach others.